# Can we use sketch UI elements directly into Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sketch-3, sketchapp

I am new to sketch 3. I have a hand on experience with Xcode and iOS development.

My question is wether we can directly use sketch elements in xcode or sketch is only used for prototyping the UI?

For example, If I design Label with a text field in sketch then can I used it as UI Label and UITextField in Xcode?

Comment: It's new but this tool might help: http://appdevelopertools.com

Answer (score 4):

In my experience as a designer that also develops in Xcode any solutions that claim to go directly from Sketch into Xcode either become vapourware after some time or don't provide a very good solution. I assume it's because Auto Layout is quite complicated and fragile.

It's best to just learn iOS development using Storyboards or possibly SwiftUI for layout. There are some elements that you can get from Sketch into Xcode such as colors, typography and iconography.

Here's a list of apps that can help you with that:

- **Zeplin**: Handoff designs and styleguides with accurate specs, assets, code snippets automatically. https://zeplin.io
- **InVision**: Prepare designs for development. https://www.invisionapp.com/feature/inspect
- **Avocado**: Open designs without design tools. Export images without preparing layers. Click on layers to get code.
  https://avocode.com/hand-off-and-inspect
- **Flawless**: A tool to compare the expected design and the real app right inside iOS Simulator (useful for designers who use Xcode or
  mobile developers). https://flawlessapp.io
- **Sketch to Xcode**: The fastest way to get colors from Sketch to Xcode. https://sketchtoxcode.com
  *Disclaimer: I'm the maker of this app.*

Answer (score 1):

There is not a way to integrate the sketch elements in xcode, you can use a sketch plug-in you can buy:
https://www.paintcodeapp.com/sketch

Comment: You're a champ, Marco.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, the design was already prepared in the Sketch and wanted to get the code from it easily. My friends and I've working on a solution for converting design into UI codes, last 2 years.

We've developed **Monday Hero** platform  to improve the development phase and actually save time for repetitive code. https://www.mondayhero.io

In Monday Hero, you can upload design and get responsive code with Storyboard, Xib or only code options. You can also select the elements on the design, group them as you wish for your code library and download it easily in like 15 minutes :) It was a dream of me to get the UI code that easily, I hope it can be also useful to you.

Comment: Wow, a pretty impressive tool. Will check it out sometime. Great job Burcu Geneci!

Comment: Thank you @Starsky, We're working on creating UI Components, so getting custom component library as a fast starter kit for mobile projects.