# Can I import a Figma or Sketch file into Xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode, sketchapp, figma

I want to make sure my app is pixel perfect. Is there a way Xcode can import a Figms or Sketch file so all the UI is created and aligned perfectly?

Comment: Define "pixel perfect". On an iPhone 5? An 11 Pro Max?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:

- Check this, [please](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39375532/can-we-use-sketch-ui-elements-directly-into-xcode). Look like this post has answers for you.

Longer answer:

- Design often draws only for one mobile resolution and that's why **it is difficult to just import** components for Xcode and use them for small (4s, SE), medium (8, 8PLUS, XS), and large screens (iPads).
- The second problem is a programmatic way to create UI. Some teams use an only programmatic way to create user interfaces.

In my opinion, it is easier to use external software like https://flawlessapp.io